# Qt inherit from QWidget class to customize and use it

Tags: qt, inheritance, qt5

I would like to inherit from "QDoubleSpinBox" and add some functionality and add to MainWindow.
the code like this compiles fine, but i don't know how to add it/place it on via code MainWindow along the other elements in designer.

.h file:

```
class DoubleSpinner : public QDoubleSpinBox
    { 
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        DoubleSpinner (QDoubleSpinBox *parent  = nullptr);



        ~DoubleSpinner(){}

        //Message();


    private:

    };
```

.cpp file:

```
DoubleSpinner::DoubleSpinner (QDoubleSpinBox *parent) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
{

}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
       ui->setupUi(this);

       ui->lineEdit->setText("0.0001");

       //DoubleSpinner ds = new DoubleSpinner;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this topic from Qt documentation if want to use custom widgets in Qt Designer:

[Creating Custom Widgets for Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html#)

You can also create layouts in Qt Designer and then instantiate and reparent your widgets to those layouts.
I recommend you to start learning Qt without using the designer to get familiar with under the hood of Qt. You can use the Qt Designer later whenever you will.

Comment: Creating custom plugins for Designer is, 99% of the time, absolutely wrong way to do this. It's a huge amount of work for essentially zero gain...

Comment: I agree with @hyde. It only makes sense when you are working in a team with separate designers and you have plenty of time and resources to take that path. I personally never used Qt Designer in my 10+ years of using Qt.